# setActionName: method purpose for NSUndoManager class

Tags: cocoa

setActionName: method description says that it set the action name for undo or redo command. But, my doubt is how the undomanager use the action name set by the above method.

Regards,
iSight

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The setActionName: method only changes the label on the Undo and Redo menu items. So, if you use

```
[undoMgr setActionName:@"Cut"]
```

the label of the Undo menu item will change to Undo Cut.